# how to create subdomain for mysql vps

Tags: mysql, apache, server-administration

I want to have a subdomain for my mysql server in my VPS. Something like mysql.mydomain.com

How is it possible with Apache2? I do not have a separate server for MySQL. I just want to have subdomain.

I hope I made sense.

Comment: I think we need more info on why you want to do this. What is your goal? Access the mysql server globally from a FQDN?

Comment: No. I want to use it for future. Like If I am going to have a different ip for my mysql all i will need to do is to change dns record. Is it even possible?

Comment: MySQL and Apache have nothing to do with one another.  If you want to put your MySQL server on a separate subdomain and ensure it is _not_ accessible via other interfaces, you'll need to add a network interface with a dedicated IP address and ask mysqld to listen only on that specific interface.

Comment: Is it possible yes, just add a CNAME record that points the subdomain to the same domain then access mysql via either domain at its port. (defaults to 3306) HOWEVER, once you add a little security in you wont be saving your self any time, short or long term, like you're going for.